# Django class based DeleteView check constraints

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, cascading-deletes

In a django application, there are two model with 1-M relationship, e.g. `Parent` and `Child`. I need to delete the Parent model object using `DeleteView` class. Before deleting the object, I need to check if it has any child objects and if there was, it returns an error message instead of deleting the object.
Currently my DeleteView, like the default is:

```
class ParentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Parent
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('parent-list')
```

Which methods should I implement to check constraints?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to override the `delete` method.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class ParentDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Parent

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        # check if object has child if yes return error
        # otherwise
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('parent-list')
```